# Science fiction short story, possibly titled "Hop for Pop," about life ending at age 30

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was printed in an anthology paper magazine, maybe *Asimov's Science Fiction* (similar to *Ellery Queen's Mystery Magazine* short stories). It would have been printed some time between 1976 and 1985.

It dealt with a society that needed to kill everyone over 30.  The phrase was "hop for pop," as they headed off to the place where they were to be killed; I think it was also the title.

Comment: Obvious _[Logan's Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run)_ vibes here (moreso the film than the novel, in respect to the age limit). That's not a short story, though.

Answer (score 29):

Some of the details differ, but this sounds a lot like *[Jamboree](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51990)* by Jack Williamson, a short story first published in 1969 in *Galaxy*.

The story seems to describe the adventure of a Boy Scout troop, happily heading off for the annual jamboree. As the story unfolds, however, it becomes more and more sinister. The troop is actually led by a robot called"Pop", and the scouts are repeatedly urged to "Hop for Pop!". The actual purpose of the Jamboree is for the oldest scouts to be broken down, and their cellular matter used to produce the next generation of children, by another machine called "Mother". Rather than happening at an age of 30 years though, this happens when the scouts are about 11.

The story is available from the [Luminist Archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QEcGfhUk_5YjEDX3PVSt1-ouUfTe2gzE/view?pli=1).

Comment: Available as [part of an anthology](https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/EB/W/Wilson_ed%20-%20Those%20Who%20Can.pdf). (Not sure about copyright there.)

Comment: The 30 years could be a mix-up with the movie *Logan's Run*, where citizens are killed at 30.

Comment: Sounds like a mix-up with Logan's Run.

Comment: The anthology is "Those Who Can" edited by Robin Scott Wilson ISBN [9780312141394](https://isbn.nu/9780312141394)